# not all chars in cell after a add_table

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Hi I have a string with 27502 chars. but if i pass the mto the xlsxwriter worksheet via ws.add_table just 10996 are written i debugged and i figured out that until here the string is ok. But I don't know how to continue to debug.

Maybe there is a limitation of the xlsxwriter package. But I don't know.

```
        # Write a shared string or an in-line string in optimisation mode.
    if self.optimization == 0:
        string_index = self.str_table._get_shared_string_index(string)
    else:
        string_index = string

    # Write previous row if in in-line string optimization mode.
    if self.optimization and row > self.previous_row:
        self._write_single_row(row)

    # Store the cell data in the worksheet data table.
    self.table[row][col] = cell_string_tuple(string_index, cell_format)

    return str_error
```

**edit:**

After a more detailed test it seams it is a excel(2007) limitation. But not a char limitation. It seams there is a new line limitation.

I did not find a official figure for excel 2007 but I tried it and figured out 254 lines is the limit.

Comment: The first thing you should check is whether this is an Excel limitation by pasting the string into an existing table. If it is not an Excel limitation then you should create an [small, complete working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.